# Blob data showing in one line in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtextpane

I've a jtextpane. the value of textpane stored as Blob in database. when I retrive the value from database I noticed the all the data set at one line but I save in different line.

Insert Code:
           try {
            conn = db.Database();

```
        stat3 = conn
                .prepareStatement("Update Knowledgebase SET Plan=? where TabID=? AND Context=?");
        stat3.setString(1, jTextPane1.getText());
        stat3.setInt(2, 1);
        stat3.setObject(3, recv);

        stat3.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Retrive Code:

```
              conn = db.Database();

        stat3 = conn
                .prepareStatement("Select Plan from Knowledgebase where TabID=? And Context=?");
        stat3.setInt(1, 1);
        stat3.setObject(2, recv);

        rs = stat3.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            jTextPane1.setText(rs.getString("Plan"));
        }
```

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: We will need more information. How do you store the data in the DB. How do you retrieve it. Have you compared the values you store vs the values you retrieve ? Have you an example of such a value ? Why not simply storing `String`s (coming from the `JTextPane`) as VARCHAR or TEXT in your database ?

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that the encoding of your database messes up the newline characters in the text retrieved from the `JTextArea`. See the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for copying text between two `JTextArea` instances. You can type in multiline text in the first area, press the button and the multiline text appears in the second area, including the line breaks

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MultiLineTextDemo {

  private JFrame testFrame;
  private JTextArea firstTextArea, secondTextArea;
  private JButton copyTextButton;

  public MultiLineTextDemo() {
    testFrame = new JFrame( "Copy text between 2 text area's" );

    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel(  );
    textPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( textPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS ) );

    firstTextArea = new JTextArea( 10, 50 );
    secondTextArea = new JTextArea( 10, 50 );
    secondTextArea.setEditable( false );
    textPanel.add( new JScrollPane( firstTextArea ) );
    textPanel.add( new JScrollPane( secondTextArea ) );

    testFrame.add( textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    copyTextButton = new JButton( "Copy text" );
    copyTextButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        copyText();
      }
    } );

    testFrame.add( copyTextButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
  }

  public JFrame getFrame() {
    return testFrame;
  }

  private void copyText(){
    secondTextArea.setText( firstTextArea.getText() );
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        MultiLineTextDemo multiLineTextDemo = new MultiLineTextDemo();
        JFrame frame = multiLineTextDemo.getFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

The [Swing text component tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) clearly specifies

> Note that the text system uses the '\n' character internally to represent newlines; for details, see the API documentation for DefaultEditorKit

So I suggest you take a close look (with a debugger for example) at the `String` you retrieve from the text area and which you store in the DB, and compare this with the `String` you retrieve afterwards from the DB. Most likely those two are not equal